# Arduino Mega ADK not recognized by Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: android, amazon-s3, arduino, galaxy, adk

I have been using the Arduino board successfully, uploading sketches without any problem. I've got most of my project running - Stepper Motor shield and motor, IR LED, everything. I just can't get my Galaxy S3 to recognize that it is connected to the board so that I can complete my project.

I am using a 9Volt battery as logic power for the board and to provide power to the G S3. I have uploaded the proper drivers to the board using the demokit sketch distributed by Google.

I have the ADK 2012 App installed from the Play Store on my G S3.

When I plug in the usb cable from my Arduino ADK to the phone the phone acts like nothing is plugged in. When I execute the ADK 2012 app on my phone I get a message stating "Your ADK is not connected".

This is both with the stock Samsung microUSB cord and with a USB OTG cord.

This is a Model SCH-I535 Verizon Phone. Not Rooted. Running Android 4.1.2

I understand that there are potentially 2 problems with my combination of board and phone:

1. adequate power to supply both board and phone.
2. using the proper cord.

I think I've addressed both issues. I have searched for months for an answer to this problem. I'd hate to break down and get a tablet as I really want to get this to work with my phone.

Has anyone found a solution to this problem?